# Android 2.2.3 Cannot load project: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I almost done other solutions given in SOW.. given in below questions.. What should I do now. Please help..

["Cannot load project: Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800546/cannot-load-project-android-studio)

Comment: Try importing instead of opening. Or, if you have few java files there, you can rebuild all your project from the scratch: open the java files with notepad, copy and paste them inside similar blank files you make, one by one, in a brand new project on A.S. Then you deal with assets. It's a dirty solution, but if you cannot find a better one...

Comment: I have used importing, same result. Now will try other. thanx statosdotcom

Comment: This generally happens when we try to open multiple instance of android studio. You can restart your system on this occasion.

Comment: Arjun Singh, if you get success based on my comment, please alert me. I would like to build a formal answer here, for you to check it as 'correct', in order to get precious points to improve my reputation in SO. Thank you. Best.

Comment: Try [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30044635/5180017) solutions.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31156804/3512555

Answer (score 0):

Close android studio using task manager "end task" option, then reopen android studio it will load the project. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio as Administrator mode. It worked for me.
[image]