# Null Pointer exception while Loading the Project

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

First of all i know [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) .
But the error is occuring when i tried to open project , i worked on project just this morning only there was a power cut in middle and when i tried to reopen project i am getting this error

Here is a screenshot

[image: Project]

whats the reason for this error?

**EDIT**

even clean option doesnot appear

[image: Clean]

Comment: Why downvote may i know reason?

Comment: this is a valid question. at least give a reason if you are downvoting.

Comment: Clean your project and use `Invalid cache and Restart` from `File` menu.

Comment: If you are opening project from recent menu or it's automatically loading, try to manually re-open project from File -> Open.

Comment: Clean option is not appearing as project is not loaded , i am doing invalidate cache and Restart , lets wait for result

Comment: You can clean your project from _Build_ option

Comment: @Piyush see the updated question, clean option doesnot appear. I tried to do Invalid cache and restart  but nothing happened studio didnot restart, even close button was not working , i force closed the studio from task manager and reopened the studio now its working and even project is loaded. I just wanted to know reason why this happened

Comment: Did you check by changing the directory means change the project location & open it from there?

Comment: i just force closed the android studio and opened it again ,now its working

Answer (score 2):

Based on another question ["Cannot load project: Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800546/cannot-load-project-android-studio).

You need to

> 1. Close Android Studio
> 2. Go to the directory home_dir/.AndroidStudio/system/cache
> 3. Remove all the files in the cache directory.
> 4. Then restart IntelliJ